# Invoke c++ Lambda Runtime by https

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, http, aws-lambda

I follow the example of [this page](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/) to create a hello world example.

```
#include <aws/lambda-runtime/runtime.h>

using namespace aws::lambda_runtime;

invocation_response my_handler(invocation_request const& request)
{
   return invocation_response::success("Hello, World!", "application/json");
}

int main()
{
   run_handler(my_handler);
   return 0;
}
```

I can invoke the function by awscli, so good so far. But when I try to invoke it with https api, the server always give me error message "Internal server error" and I cannot find any useful message from the cloud watch.

I create the api gateway with following steps

"Add trigger->API gateway->creating new api->open(security)".

[image]

After that I copy the api, and start a post request by python.

```
requests.post("https://blahblah", json={})
```

The other lambda functions written by python work with the api gateway, but it don't work with the lambda function written by c++ api, what do I miss?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please follow this link [c++ runtime for aws lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/)

for invocation using postman or curl  https://<api_url>/default/<function_name>

Comment: Note: answers that are very brief and/or are questions back to the poster should probably be comments. You only need 50 rep points to comment under a question - could you move this there?